# Does the front rim joist have the strength to support this deck?

Tags: framing, deck

Should I just lag bolt the ledger to the rim, or should I reinforce the rim joist with say a simpson strongtie htt4, and carriage bolt, and cut some cats to attach it? It seems that if there were a lot of people on the deck it could potentially rip the rim joist off the house.[image: new deck]

[image: 1st fl frame]

Comment: Assuming there is no significant cantilever force (and there doesn't appear to be), isn't all the strain shear rather than tension?

Comment: I'm sure most of it is. I'm more of a plumber than a carpenter, but I've built a few decks in my time. I'm wondering if I'm just being a worry wort about this.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I won't be able to answer this in any case, but I expect those that could would benefit from some dimensions, either in your drawing or in your text.

Comment: What is the furthest distance from the house out to the beam? What is the length of the cantilever? Do you live in a seismically active area or a high wind area?

Comment: Does the front rim joist sit on a plate that sits on the concrete basement wall or does it cantilever past the basement wall?

Comment: Voting to close. Questions remain unanswered and OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 1):

What he meant by "load beams must be on posts" is self-explanatory.  You may not simply use carriage bolts to attach your beam into the side of a post, like was done way back in the day.  All the shear load would be carried by the bolts and eventually fail.  Code requires that the beam rest ON THE POST, either right on top and secured with approved hardware (example Simpson post-to-beam), or notch the post and set the beam inside the notch, bolted to it.

Comment: While good advice, the question (though unclear) seems to be about the ledger on the house, not the beams on the posts.

Answer (score -1):

Just don't exceed maximum overhang which it sounds & looks like what you are referring to?. Load beams must be ON POSTS, not hanging from them. From diagram and the height of deck what you have is not to code..imminent failure that will eventually happen. Study up and do it the right way sir.

Comment: Why do you say, “Load beams must be on posts”? That is not true. Where in the code does it say that?

Comment: Why do you say, “What you have is not to code...imminent failure that will eventually happen”? Please explain what is not to code. Where in the code is this prohibited? How is it going to fail?

Comment: I think when you say, “Study up and do the right way sir” that is what I want to say to you: Study up and stop making outlandish statements that you cannot support.